# Quad Channel Memory Running Dual Channel Configuration

Tags: memory, motherboard, dual-channel, cpu-z, threadripper

I have a ASRock x399 Fatal1ty Professional Gaming motherboard with a AMD 2950x Threadripper and 4x32gb Corsair Vengence 3600mhz DDR4 memory (all the same type/speed/etc). When I go into the bios, it says "Quad Channel Configuration". However, when I run CPU-Z, it says dual channel.

I made sure I put the memory in the correct slots as the manual says. The manual says it will run in quad channel configuration, but I also checked with the tool aida64 and it says dual channel as well. However, hwinfo says there are 4 memory channels active. So i'm not exactly sure which is correct. Is it doing some sort of dual dual-channel config? As far as I can tell my hardware should support quad channel memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating CPU-Z to the latest version. Had the same problem with the 1.91.0. Just updated to 1.92.0 and it now shows quad.

Cheers